# contours labels in 3D

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

Is there any way to put contours labels in 3D plots? Clabel is apparently not implemented in 3D

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1,1,10),np.linspace(-1,1,10))
z=-(x**2+y**2)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
C=ax.contour(x,y,z)
ax.clabel(C)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
C=ax.contour(x,y,z,zdir='z',offset=-2)
ax.clabel(C)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As [clabel is not implemented](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html) and the return value is None, there is indeed no point in calling `clabel()` for the time being. You can use the `C.levels` attribute to [manually add labels to the graph](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/text3d_demo.html).

It won't have the nice `inline` feature that hides the contour under the labels though.